# Is it possible to add an IP address to the Google Console's list of allowed javascript authorised origins?

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, ip-address, google-developers-console, google-cloud-console

I have implemented the Sign in with google option in my web app. (JSP page, Tomcat server, localhost:8080)

Google sign-in works fine while running it in localhost, but the sign-in option is not working while running the web app using IP address, it results in `"Access blocked: Sign in with google’s request is invalid". Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch.`

So I thought I need to `add the IP address in the developer google cloud console as an authorized origin, But it won't allow IP as an authorized javascript origin.`

How can I add my IP address(172.22....) as an authorised javascript origin, So that sign-in with google option works?
[clich here to more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIEx9.png)

Basically, I'm trying http://172.22.... instead of http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Using private IPs is not allowed.

See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies#secure-response-handling and the `host` section of https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation.